# How does an equation that's not fully factored, end up outputting solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

In a textbook I stumbled across this:

> $(32-8a+2b)x+(32-6a+b)=0$
>       Thus, $32-8a+2b=0$ (1) , $32-6a+b=0$ (2)

Now how exactly does that first equation, imply the 2 solutions?
In this case the LHS doesn't consist of factors only. So how are these the solutions?

Comment: A polynomial is identically zero if and only if all coefficients are zero.

Comment: The first equation is not a single equation : it is true for every value of $x$. I think this is what forces the conclusion : if a polynomial is equal to zero, every coefficient is equal  to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you write doesn’t allow you to write that both coefficients are equal to zero. 
However, had you used correct mathematical symbols such as $\forall{x}, ax+b =0 $, you could conclude that $a=0$ and $b=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since, the equation $mx + c = 0 $ should hold for every $x$ then it makes coefficients $m, c$ equal to zero due to [the fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).